# Silverlight databinding

Tags: silverlight

I have to bind sql table to one of the grid in my silverlight page.

I have seen all the examples in web using wcf services or web services for databinding.

Can i use datalayer dll (regular way of datalayer classes) to bind data to silverlight pages.

Anyone please suggest a good article on this.I am used to the regular way of devolopment like datalayer as dll.

Is this possible in silverlight?If this is possible why system.data dll's are missing from the project.?

Thanks

SNA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Data.dlls are missing from Silverlight because Silverlight is a subset of .Net designed to run in a browser - and browsers don't usually have databases available! For this reason you usually have to create custom objects and return these through a WCF service.

[Scott Guthrie's tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-2-end-to-end-tutorial-building-a-digg-search-client.aspx) might be helpful as a guide to building Data Driven silverlight applciations.

Looking [a few months into the future](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/06/09/ria-services-roadmap-updated.aspx), you'll soon be able to use [.Net RIA Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/19/what-is-net-ria-services.aspx) (Rich Internet Applications) for this kind of thing. Here's a link to [the preview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=76bb3a07-3846-4564-b0c3-27972bcaabce&displaylang=en)